# What is the android audio buffer format in HAL?

Tags: android, audio, hal

I am trying to integrate some library in android HAL.I need to pass the audio data to my library in blocks of left sample and right sample as below:

**LLLLLRRRRR**

***Where L and R stand for left and right respectively***. I am not able to understand the format in which the HAL is given the buffer by the audioflinger. Can someone give some pointers? Is it in this below format?

**LRLRLRLRLRLR**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it in this below format?
>
> LRLRLRLRLRLR

Yes, stereo audio data is interleaved that way. I don't have any piece of documentation to point to that explicitly states this, but you can infer that that is the case by looking at various places in the Android source code. For example, [in this function](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libeffects/downmix/EffectDownmix.c?h=aosp-new/master#n815) in the Downmix effect which converts 5.1 audio to stereo, you'll see that for each 5.1 sample it writes one `int16_t` representing the left output, directly followed by an `int16_t` representing the right output.

Comment: I figured that out.Thanks.